# How to modify backpropagation for a standard multilayer network including a scalar gain at each layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

Considering a standard multilayer network including a scalar gain at each layer. The net input at layer m would be computed as : 
n^m = β^m [W^m α^m − 1 + b^m]

where β^m is the scalar gain at layer m . This gain would be trained like the weights and biases of the network.

How can I modify the backpropagation algorithm for this new network ?

What would be a new equation added to update β^m ?

This is an exercise from this [book](http://hagan.okstate.edu/NNDesign.pdf) .

E11.13

Neural Network Design (2nd Edition) - Martin T. Hagan, Howard B. Demuth, Mark H. Beale, Orlando De Jesus

Comment: Treat the gain like a bias, but multiplicative (I'm assuming you're multiplying the inputs). That way you can easily modify it

Comment: @Recessive yes , but which will be the equation to update the new scalar gain ?

Comment: [these](https://imgur.com/a/37Ujhkn) are the equations i have wrote so far

Comment: I'm not really sure what some of those variables represent. Though I can guess, it's often really difficult to decipher back prop in pure mathematical form. I can give you the equation for just the scalar gain (assuming it is 1 scalar gain per layer), which would be: https://imgur.com/a/8EA5Val where a_n is activation n before the scalar gain (1 indexed) and β_n is the scalar gain at layer n, which I think is as simple as you'd find it.

Comment: Ah sorry, E is the error function, so when I say ∂E/∂β, I mean the partial derivative of the Error with respect to a scalar gain. I'm not sure about a PDF, I just quickly wrote that equation in latex so I could show you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written the answer in LaTeX

[image: page 1 / 2]

[image: page 2 / 2]